# Setting hidden field in edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating posts to blogs. Here's code to create post

```
= simple_form_for post do |f|
      = f.error_notification
        = f.input :title
        = f.input :content
        = f.hidden_field :blog_id, value: params[:blog_id]
        = f.button :submit
```

Creating works fine, but when I tried to edit created post with same form a got an error.
Console log:

> "post"=>{"title"=>"xzcascdasd", "content"=>"", "blog_id"=>""},
>   "commit"=>"Update Post", "id"=>"2"}

Should I set here blog_id? It doesnt work without blog_id too. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is blog_id coming from? If it is a URL param this might work. Perhaps the post belongs_to a blog, in which case you get the id from the model.

Comment: please, post error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= f.hidden_field :blog_id, value: params[:blog_id]

is params[:blog_id] existing on this page ??
```

Comment: How can I get it?

Comment: you can set in controller and can use like  value: variable